# Smooth joins are not as smooth as shown in the tutorial

Tags: modeling, smooth, sculpt-mode

> Please note: I'm using Blender 2.78 in a Windows 7 - 32 bits - PC.

I add 2 cubes and for then I follow these steps:

- Add a vertical loop cut at the middle of the cube.
- Delete vertices.
- Add "Mirror" and "Subdivision Surface" modifiers (*the later with view: 2*).
- Shift + A, then Scale, then, Apply all modifiers.
- Select the two cubes and then Ctrl + j = join the objects.
- Click on "Smooth".
- On "Sculpt Mode", select the "Smooth" brush (*or any brush and whil holding shift*), smoothing the joins of the mesh/clay, in this case.

At this point, I don't see the "smoothing" applied to the joins:

*Current result - looks like the mesh is dissolver and not smoothed:*

[image: current result - joins are not smoothed]

I would like to try [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEOB0vlBkKgvxsfyLQwPWy3JdMNcRcf2), but, **I don't know if this can be achievable using Blender 2.78c**.

In the tutorials I've found, versions of Blender 3.0 and upper are used, and also, the "Remesh" option - which I found in Blender 2.78 is a *modifier* and don't get the same or similar results as shown in the tutorials.

(*With the current version of Blender I'm using*), it is possible to achieve a similar result as is shown in the tutorial?

Desired result:

[image: Desired result to obtain using Blender 2.78]

> I believe I don't get the similar results due to the lack of cuts in the base mesh and the limitations of Blender 2.78 compared to newer versions, but, I would like to know what I'm missing, if can continue trying or just plain keep looking for other types of tutorials.

> I'll upgrade my system once I get a better grasp on how can achieve a similar result as shown in the tutorial.

Comment: Hello, if these are 2 meshes it won't be able to smooth the joint, it needs to be one mesh, you can select one in Edit mode and Ctrl F > Boolean

Comment: Hello, I follow your reply, but, the shortcut didn't add a boolean. I searched and I found the "boolean" modifier - what I did was: add the boolean modifier and the operation "union" and the meshes did joined. Then, I smoothed the intersections and it looks fine - see [image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpNmO.png). Did I follow your comment correctly?. Thanks

Comment: OK great then! Actually if the Boolean modifier worked it means that the 2 pieces were 2 separate objects and not 2 separate meshes within one object